# SqlAlchemy: Temporarily disable database constraints for big insert transactions

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

As part of a daily process, I insert big chunks of data which I know for a fact do not invalidate any foreign key constraints. To speed things up, several resources suggest to temporarily remove any indexes or constraints and re-apply them after the insert is ready. I'm aware this is risky but would still like to give that a try using SqlAlchemy. I have not added any manual constraints and the only constraints are the ones defined by SqlAlchemy due to foreign and primary keys.

My question is: how can I, using SqlAlchemy API, temporarily remove any constraint/index, perform a set of transactions and then apply the auto-generated constraints again?

I'm hoping there's something a little more convenient than doing that manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you populating tables from scratch, or just adding to them? Recreating the index might not buy you much if it needs to re-index a bunch of existing data; this advice is more geared towards initial loading. Dropping constraints is not that helpful either, as it will check the FKs anyway when the constraints are added back. There are ways to bypass FK checks entirely, but the database user doing the `INSERT` would need to be given some permissions by a superuser. Is this an option?

Comment: @NickBarnes I am populating from scratch and changing permissions by a superuser is indeed an option. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know SqlAlchemy, but this isn't terribly hard to do with SQL.

For a table `my_table`, build a set of `DROP CONSTRAINT` / `ADD CONSTRAINT` statements:

```
SELECT
  format('ALTER TABLE %s DROP CONSTRAINT %s', conrelid::regclass, conname),
  format('ALTER TABLE %s ADD CONSTRAINT %s %s', conrelid::regclass, conname, pg_get_constraintdef(oid))
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE conrelid = 'my_table'::regclass
```

...and similarly for indexes, skipping over anything tied to a constraint:

```
SELECT
  'DROP INDEX ' || indexrelid::regclass,
  pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid)
FROM pg_index
WHERE indrelid = 'my_table'::regclass AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_constraint WHERE conindid = indexrelid)
```

Then just run the drop scripts, load your data, and run the add scripts when you're done (all within a transaction, of course).

There's one downside: When the foreign key constraints are added back, all of the data will be re-checked, which is a lot of unnecessary work if you're confident that it's all valid.

There are a couple of ways to suppress the checks while leaving the FK constraints in place (though both require superuser privileges):

- [`ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html), which includes the system triggers used for FK checks. (This is permanent, you'll need to re-enable the triggers when you're done.)
- [`SET session_replication_role = 'replica'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SESSION-REPLICATION-ROLE) basically declares you to be a replication process (where it's assumed that the FK checks have been already been performed at the source).

The simplest way to pass one of these privileges on to a non-superuser is to give it a default `session_replication_role`:

```
ALTER ROLE data_loader SET session_replication_role = 'replica'
```

Anything more fine-grained than that would probably need to be wrapped in a `SECURITY DEFINER` function (executed with the privileges of its creator, rather than its caller) which the loading process can invoke at will. E.g. to disable triggers for the rest of the current transaction:

```
CREATE FUNCTION disable_triggers_for_current_transaction() RETURNS void AS $$
  SET LOCAL session_replication_role = 'replica'
$$
LANGUAGE sql
SECURITY DEFINER;
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION disable_triggers_for_current_transaction() FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION disable_triggers_for_current_transaction() TO data_loader;
```

Or to disable triggers on a particular table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION disable_triggers(TableID REGCLASS) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE pg_catalog.format('ALTER TABLE %s DISABLE TRIGGER ALL', TableID);
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER;
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION disable_triggers(REGCLASS) FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION disable_triggers(REGCLASS) TO data_loader;
```

Of course, if you decide to go with any of these options, you'll want to keep the FK constraints in place when building those `DROP` scripts; just add `AND contype <> 'f'` to that first `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for something that specifically uses SQLAlchemy and avoiding writing all of that SQL manually.

Comment: If you create a role and set replica mode using `ALTER ROLE data_loader SET session_replication_role = 'replica'` then you can 'use SQLAlchemy' by simply switching the role when you create then engine.

Answer (score 4):

As before described you can turn of the FK checking for different databases in different ways. In pgsql it would be for instance:

```sql
SET session_replication_role = replica;
```

In order insert data into your database without FK-checks, you have to connect to the database with sqlalchemy and execute the SQL statement which turns off the checks. Within the same connection you can then operate without FK-checks.

This is an example if you want to insert your data with the help of pandas.

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine("postgresql://<your-connection>")

df = pd.read_csv(<your-path>)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute("SET session_replication_role = replica;")
    df.to_sql('categories', if_exists="append", con=connection)
```

Note that is solution is specific to pgsql and the statement to turn of the FK checks varies from database to database. To turn the checks on again for the same session you need to run.

```sql
SET session_replication_role = DEFAULT;
```

For new session the `session_replication_role` is set to `DEFAULT` anyways, so nothing to worry about.